# Why are these types incompatible? Potential workarounds?

Tags: kotlin, inheritance

I am (attempting) to write a library that supports both mutable and immutable representations of genetic data. Obviously, the mutable representation of the data should adhere to the same interface as the immutable representation because it can perform all the same functionality as the immutable representation. This is where I start to run into some trouble.

The data is represented in a tree structure. Any node that has children is an “Ancestor” while nodes that carry genetic information are called a “Feature.” A node that is an ancestor but not a feature is a “Genome,” which represents the root of the entire tree.

Here is a reduced version of the code to show subtyping relationships.

```
public sealed interface Ancestor : Iterable<Feature>
public sealed interface MutableAncestor : Ancestor, Iterable<MutableFeature>
public sealed interface Feature
public sealed interface MutableFeature : Feature
```

My assumption was that since the iterator only ever produces and never consumes the type specified, that this type of override would be legal. However, the compiler produce the following error “Type parameter T of iterable has inconsistent values: Feature, MutableFeature.” It is not clear to me why this arrangement would cause an issue. I want to ensure that the client can get access to a node as a MutableAncestor and concisely iterate over its descendents without having to cast each one of them to a MutableFeature.

Is there a good workaround to accomplish what I want to accomplish?

Essentially I expected this to type-check fine because Iterable only needs to provide the iterator() function and `Iterator<Feature>` is a supertype of `Iterator<MutableFeature>` so I am just confused.

Comment: Yeah it does provide the iterator() function, but then what does it iterate over? Feature or MutableFeature?

Comment: My confusion is that it's acceptable for me to put the following into the bodies of the interfaces. In Ancestor, I can put

`override fun iterator(): Iterator<Feature>`

and in MutableAncestor, I can put

`override fun iterator(): Iterator<MutableFeature>`

and this does not cause errors. So fundamentally, the two interfaces can maintain the appropriate iterator contracts. Whether it iterates over Feature or MutableFeature (at least in theory) should just depend on whether the Ancestor is statically known to be a MutableAncestor, no?

Answer (score 2):

I believe my question is a restatement of [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13380/Consider-relaxation-of-arguments-consistency-for-covariant-supertypes). While I think what I want to accomplish makes sense in this instance, my understanding is that allowing it would open up some interoperability issues with Java.

The workaround I have settled on is this

```
public sealed interface Ancestor {
    public operator fun iterator(): Iterator<Feature>
}
public sealed interface MutableAncestor: Ancestor {
    public override fun iterator(): Iterator<MutableFeature>
}
public sealed interface Feature
public sealed interface MutableFeature : Feature
```

This allows for the use of Ancestor and MutableAncestor in for loops despite not explicitly calling them implementations of `Iterable`.